# s3 - use CLI to make directory public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is it possible to use the s3 cli to change to ACL of existing files, without using `sync` ? I got about 1TB of data on my bucket, I'd like to change their ACL without syncing it on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make Amazon S3 content 'public':

- Change the Access Control List (ACL) on an **individual object**
- Create a Bucket Policy on a **bucket or path within a bucket**

It sounds like you want to make all objects within a given directory public, so you should use an **Amazon S3 Bucket Policy**, such as this one from [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/directory/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

You can add this policy by the AWS CLI, but it's much easier to do it in the Amazon S3 management console (Permissions tab).